# Unity shader is changing the selectable area to the original texture it used

Tags: unity, shaders, materials

I know a little about shaders, but not much. I cobbled one together to to light my sprites, and it's working great if not for one thing:

[image]

I originally tested the shader with a chair texture.
I made a new material from that same shader with all different inputs that are distinctly table-shaped, but unity insists on making the clickable area the same shape and position of the original chair. I have no idea why.

When I set the alpha cutoff to zero, it uses the entire quad again.
Based on this, I'm guessing somehow the alpha of the original texture is filtering through somehow.

I can set the cutoff to zero for the time being, but I still want to know what's happening if anyone could help me understand

Edit: setting the alpha cutoff to zero makes the display a square again but the clickable area is still the same as the little chair in the corner there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The shader had a few inputs marked as `[HideInInspector]`. When I removed the flag, the `_MainTex("BaseMap", 2D)` was set to the diffuse chair texture.

Mystery solved.